# Cant hide leaflet routing machine route instruction

Tags: angular, leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

I would like to hide or display this routing machine instruction in more pleasing way, but once I turn off the auto-route, waypoints route drawing is also turning off....I have also tried the show:false and other css to hide it but still dont works for me.

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this link [link](https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-routing-machine/issues/608)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

First get `routeControl`

```
this.routeControl = L.Routing.control({})
```

After that, modify `routingControlParent`

```
const routingControlContainer = this.routeControl.getContainer()
const controlContainerParent = routingControlContainer.parentNode
controlContainerParent.removeChild(routingControlContainer)
```

I guess, what you are doing is removing routing information html element.